# How to write conditional regular expressions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Delete regex based on lookup. How to do a lookup on a regex?

Comment: A regular expression alone does only *match* things, not return any strings. What are you doing, how do you delete characters? Why does it need to be regex? What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: JavaScript regex always return new strings. IF x="ctrl+" or x="ctrl+F"the following regex works                                  y = x.replace(/\+(?! [a-zA-Z0-9])/g, "")

Comment: It's not the regex that returns a string, it's the `replace` function. It seems like you want a positive lookahead and remove the whitespace, then your regex should work - you *only* want to delete pluses that *are followed* by characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [**lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/\+(?!$)/
```

This matches only if a `+` is followed by other characters (not the end of the string).

I assume you know how to remove characters from a string matching a regular expression.

Comment: str = "ctrl+f2"; str.replace(/\+(?! [a-zA-Z0-9])/g, ""); why does this not work?

Comment: Because the expression only matches if `+` is followed by a character **not** in `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. `f` is in `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex `Ctrl\+.+`. If there is a match, then replace occurrences of "+" with the empty string.

Example in code use:

```
var str = "Ctrl+F2";
var match = str.match(/Ctrl\+.+/);
if (match) {
    str.replace("+", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to just erase all occurences of '+' from your string except if its the last character.

```
var text = "Ctrl+F2 + Ctrl+";
var newText = text.substring(0,text.length-1).split('+').join('')+text[text.length-1];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JoeSham/vLns7Lfh/2/